# Replace frontpage to a page with wildcards

Tags: 7, panels

I've created a page that receives a term name argument and displays a panel with several views which serves content according to this term name.

The thing is, I want to make that page my default frontpage, with a default term, but everytime I try setting it Drupal sents an error message:

> You cannot make this page your site home page if it uses %
>   placeholders.

I'm even trying to set the url manually, such as `myCustomPage/myCustomTerm` i.e. `customFrontPage/NaturalUser` and it shows the following error message:

> the url 'myCustomPage/myCustomTerm' is not valid or you don't have permission
>   to access it.

Is there any other way to change this?

Comment: I think you can make the context optional using ! rather than % and set your views up with a default argument of the term you want. The page path for the front page would then omit the term argument. But I haven't tried this so there may be more to it.

Comment: Yes! that's exactly what I did. You can post an answer and i'll set it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the term context of your page optional using ! rather than %, then set up your views so the default argument (when no term is supplied) is the one you want.

Your page should then work with no argument, ie. at path "myCustomPage". When all OK, you can assign that path as the front page for your site.